# How to put a tab bar only in certain place in the app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I want to put a tab bar for one place in my app. From there i can load some other view controllers, but that's it. I don't want it for my whole application. All examples I read through are making the tab bar controller as the rootviewcontroller of the window.

So how do i do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

his may help you, Consider your view controller is HomeView where from you are going to push a tab bar controller, The HomeView is loaded in view at below:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    HomeView *homeview = [[HomeView alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeView" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeview];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

then the .h, .m and .xib files of HomeView are going to be as follows:

In HomeView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HomeView : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}
-(IBAction)loadTabBar:(id)sender;
@end
```

and the HomeView.m is:

```
@implementation HomeView

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(IBAction)loadTabBar:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

and the .xib file must be as follows:

[image]
The tabBarController `IBOutlet` must be connected to the UITabBarController that on the .xib file. And that `UITabBarController` with two view controllers named `FirstViewController`, `SecondViewController`. Moreover that the HomeView must be inside a `UINavigationController`.

If not clarified with this answer, I'll update with detailed explanation.
The above is a way of loading tab bar controller using XIB method.

You can do this by coding like below by changing something in `IBAction`(button action) , In HomeView.m file:

```
#import "HomeView.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation HomeView

-(IBAction)loadTabBar:(id)sender
{
    FirstViewController *firstView = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstView, secondView, nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make tabBar in app delegate and then add when ever you want using this

```
-(void)addTabBarController
{
    AppDelegate *appdelegte =(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    //[[[appdelegte navigationController] view]removeFromSuperview];

    [[appdelegte window]addSubview:[[appdelegte tabcontroller]view]];

    [[appdelegte tabcontroller]setSelectedIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: then what you want?..just add this whenever you want and remove it when ever you want to remove]